# Cannot install @angular/cli on Linux currently running Parrot.sec

Tags: node.js, angular, git, npm, angular-cli

I get this error whenever I run `npm install -g @angular/cli`

```
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Cloning into bare repository '/home/jonah/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-515723dd'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/cli and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install angular/cli
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'angular/cli'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.11.0-parrot6-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! cwd /home/jonah/.npm-global/lib
npm ERR! node -v v8.9.3
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path angular/cli
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jonah/.npm-global/lib/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Are you running this as root? Or, have you tried running it with sudo?

Comment: What is your npm version?

Comment: I see now that your npm version is 1.4.21. That will not work. You need to update to the latest version, which is 5.6.0. At a minimum, you need to be at version 3.

Comment: @R.Richards thanks a lot its up and running now